# alternative proof of sup (S + T) = sup (S) + sup (T)

Tags: real-analysis

I am not sure why in my textbook there is a long proof for this because on the pages before this was prooven:

Let $S = \{ x \mid a \leq x \leq b \hbox{ and } x \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Then $\sup S = b$ must hold.

EDIT: also $\inf S=a$ follows. But the proof for $\sup S$ does not depend on there being a lower bound to $S$ this can be modified to be:

Let $S = \{ x \mid x \leq b \hbox{ and } x ∈ \mathbb{R} \}$. Then $\sup S = b$ must hold.

With this you can  instantly proove $\sup (S + T) = \sup (S) + \sup (T)$ 
since from $s \leq \sup  S$  and $t\leq  \sup  T$ we get $s+t \leq \sup S + \sup T$ and so we get $\sup (S+T)=\sup S + \sup T$.

I just don't see why the book goes the long way when we already just did the work. Or am I just getting some logic completely wrong here?

Comment: You have only proved an inequality, not equality.

Comment: The problem is that $S+T$ in general is not as nice as closed interval. So from $s+t\le \sup S+\sup T$, you can only get $\sup (S+T)\le \sup S+\sup T$

Comment: But does this argument not disregard. If S = { x | a ≤ x ≤ b and x ∈ R } .Then sup (S) = b must hold?

Comment: Hi pindakaas, you are exactly right [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7002/81923). Due to the dominant users and moderators wrongly calling all high-level technical theoretical physics questions that contain LaTex "homework", closing them and now even deleting answers(!), Physics SE has became useless for people interested in learning physics at an advanced  technical level. Please feel free to repost your deleted answer at a better place [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/33079/quantum-liouville-propagator-operator-trace-identity), where it will be welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a\le x\le b\}$, then it's of course true that $b=\sup S$: indeed, $b\le x$, for all $x\in S$ and $b\in S$, so $b$ is actually the maximum of $S$.

When you have two sets $S$ and $T$ (subsets of $\mathbb{R}$), then
$$
S+T=\{x+y:x\in S,y\in T\}
$$
is the set of all numbers that can be expressed as the sum of an element in $S$ with an element in $T$.

Assume both sets are bounded (and non empty). We wish to prove that
$$
\sup(S+T)=\sup S+\sup T
$$

If $x\in S$ and $y\in T$, then $x\le\sup S$ and $y\le\sup T$, so $x+y\le\sup S+\sup T$. Therefore $\sup S+\sup T$ is an upper bound for $S+T$ and, by definition of supremum, $\sup(S+T)\le\sup S+\sup T$.

Conversely, we want to see that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\sup S+\sup T-\varepsilon$ is *not* an upper bound for $S+T$, so it will follow that $\sup S+\sup T$ is the *least* upper bound of $S+T$.

Since $\sup S-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ is not an upper bound of $S$, there exists $x\in S$ such that $\sup S-\frac{\varepsilon}{2} < x$. Similarly, there exists $y\in T$ such that $\sup T-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<y$.

It follows that
$$
\sup S+\sup T-\varepsilon<x+y
$$
Since $x+y\in S+T$, we have what we wanted.

---

Note that the set $(S+T)'=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\le\sup S+\sup T\}$ can be ***very*** different from $S+T$. Just take $S=\{1\}$ and $T=\{2\}$; then $S+T=\{3\}$ (one element set), while $(S+T)'$ contains infinitely many elements.

Comment: @pindakaas The problem is that the question is very difficult to understand

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer but it does not really adress the question since (S+T)′={x∈R:x≤supS+supT} is not what i am talking about but (S+T)={x∈R|x=s+t , s ∈ S, t ∈ T,  x≤supS+supT  } which is identical to S+T={x+y|x∈S,y∈T}

Comment: @pindakaas Of course the set $\{x:x=s+t,s\in S,t\in T, x\le \sup S+\sup T\}$ equals $S+T$, because the last condition (that is, $x\le\sup S+\sup T$) is redundant. However, you seem to have the idea that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval, which is clearly false.

Comment: exactly. And we know if a subset of $ \mathbb{R}$ has such a bound then it is the supremum right? So proof done! Or thats my theory ^^. I would love to get why this conclusion is not allowed. It does not need to be an intervall it just needs to be defined with a bound like that one side to have this property. Or is that wrong too?

Comment: @pindakaas Sorry, but you have wrong ideas about what's the supremum of a set. The fact that every bounded set of reals has a supremum is a deep fact about the real numbers. No “instant” proofs are valid, I'm afraid.

Comment: I know this it is used to define the real numbers. BUT i can prove that. If S={x∣x≤b and x∈R}. Then sup(S)=b must hold. If this is true then it proves my assertion doesn't it?

Comment: @pindakaas The fact that $\sup\{x:a\le x\le b\}=b$ is trivial.

Comment: possible, but if i know that b=Sup(S)+Sup(T) as in the above case then the proof is done right?

Comment: @pindakaas I don't know what you're talking about: you never say what $T$ is, so how can the proof be right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22492/discussion-between-pindakaas-and-egreg).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that $S+T$ is not defined as

$$S+T=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid\inf S + \inf T\le x\le\sup S+\sup T \}$$

It is defined as

$$S+T=\{s+t\mid s\in S,t\in T\}$$

So you can not use your previous result that if $X=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\le x \le b\}$ then $\sup X=b$. While it is true that $s+t\le \sup S+\sup T$, this is not how the set is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i don't get it. I know this to be true about the set $S+T$. So i can just add it to the definition and it remains the same set rigth? By this logic i don't see why my argument is wrong. If $(S+T)'=\{x∈R∣x≤supS+supT\}=(S+T)$ then anything i can say about $(S+T)'$ will hold for $(S+T)$ i really don't get why this is flawed logic.

Comment: @pindakaas: Sometimes $S+T\ne(S+T)'$. $S+T$ has the extra condition that all its members must be of the form $s+t$, which $(S+T)'$ does not have.

Comment: Sorry your right that was not my intention. This is what i ment (S+T)′:={x= s+t∣s∈S,t∈T, x≤ supS+supT } This is the same subset of R as (S+T) right? So what we get from: X={x∈R∣a≤x≤b} then supX=b. Is that sup (S + T) = sup (S) + sup (T). I mean x≤ supS+supT for x $\in  S+T$ is just something we know about S+T just that it doesn't show up in the definition does not mean we have to ignore it.

Comment: @pindakaas: Consider the set $X'=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\le x\le b-1\}$. For all $x\in X'$, it is true that $x\le b$, so we can add that condition to the definition. So now $X'=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\le x\le b-1\text{ and }x\le b\}$. Can we now conclude that $\sup X'=b$, just because $x\le b$ is one of the conditions?

Comment: @pindakaas: Just like in that example above, you can not ignore the other conditions in the definition, of $S+T$ which might remove important members from the set. Here, $X'$ removes from $X$ those members which determine the supremum, and hence $\sup X'\ne\sup X$. It turns out that limiting the members of $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x\le\sup S+\sup T\}$ to be of the form $s+t$ has no effect on the supremum, but you have to justify this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22490/discussion-between-pindakaas-and-regret).

Comment: @pindakaas: I am going to be in chat for a little while right now, drop by if you can.